# Using RxJava2 to concatenate 2 string-lists and write to a text file in child thread

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have 2 string lists, which needed to be merged and then written to a file.
I am not sure which Rx-operator to use.

I am able to achieve the merge part bu unsure how to proceed with file operations (open, write and close)

```
List<String> collectionNames = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> collectionRollNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

//This method fill the names in the list
prepareCollectionNames(collectionNames);

//This method fill the roll numbers in the list
prepareCollectionRollNumbers(collectionRollNumbers);

Observable.fromIterable(collectionNames)
          .zipWith(collectionRollNumbers, 
          (name, rollNumber)->String.format("%s,%s", name, rollNumber)
          .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(concatedString->Log.d(TAG, "This concated string to be written to a file"));
```

Please suggest how to proceed from here.

Please note all these operations should happen in child thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an observable from an iterable, therefore the Observable is push based. rxjava immediately pumps values.

Hence you could open your file at the beginning and close it using the onCompletion part of subscribe. There is also a onSubscribe possibility as a parameter to subscribe, but I avoided this, to avoid the need of a global variable to a file instance.

This is the most detailed definition of subscribe:

```
public final Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError, Action onComplete, Consumer<? super Disposable> onSubscribe);
```

Here is an example. I used not a file writer but a string writer, but that should make no difference.

The processsing is done within an IO - thread by using **Schedulers.io()**. Additional each step writes out its thread name.

```
private static Writer writer = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<String> collectionNames = Arrays.asList("test1", "test2", "test3");

    List<String> collectionRollNumbers = Arrays.asList("50", "52", "54");

    System.out.println("main thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    Observable.fromIterable(collectionNames)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .zipWith(collectionRollNumbers,
                    (name, rollNumber) -> {
                        System.out.println("zip thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        return String.format("%s,%s\n", name, rollNumber);
                    })
            .subscribe(
                    concatedString -> {
                        if (writer == null) {
                            //open "File" thread
                            System.out.println("open thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            writer = new StringWriter();
                        }

                        //write "File" part 
                        System.out.println("subscribe item thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println(concatedString);
                        writer.write(concatedString);
                    },
                    error -> System.out.println(error),
                    () -> {
                        //Close "File" part 
                        System.out.println("close thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println("close output stream");
                        writer.close();
                    });
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("result= " + writer.toString());
}
```

Running this results in

```
main thread=main
zip thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
open thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
subscribe item thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
test1,50

zip thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
subscribe item thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
test2,52

zip thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
subscribe item thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
test3,54

close thread=RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
close output stream
result= test1,50
test2,52
test3,54
```

Comment: Well this solution don't put file operations of open, write and close in a child thread.

Comment: Only string merge is in child not the rest of operations.

Comment: Updated my answer to change to a different thread. Only file open is done within the main thread. I am not on Android therefore I cannot use AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(). Or do you explicitly want the file open and close within the main thread?

Comment: Nothing on main thread!
Any file operation is blocking including open call. Hence I need file open also in the child thread.

Comment: Then you described it not very well in your request. I updated my answer. The problem now is, you have to keep a class global handle to your file or in my case to the writer.

Comment: Not optimized... For every concatenated string produced .... If-condition will be checked for availability of stream ....

Comment: This answer is a solution. It should give you a direction to go. Stackoverflow is not there to solve your questions but to help you to do it on your own.

Comment: Appreciate your help. But this was the place where I was stuck. I was not able to find a proper rx operator to join in manner that one provides a file and other a concatenated string. All the possible solutions I had were not optimized. One such solution was to create List of concatenated strings and then zip with file. But that's also not optimized. I cannot put such a complex question on stackoverflow in a single shot so that a wider audience can contribute. This approach is taken otherwise by you.